# Recover files from mac in recovery mode - apfs missing

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, startup, apfs

I'm trying to recover files from my mom's mac that is not working. It's a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015).

Trying to boot it up results in the folder with a question mark. Trying to boot into single user mode also shows that result.

I've booted it into recovery mode. Earlier I was able to access the files using **apfs unlock "Macintosh HD"** and then I could copy them out. However, the last time I was trying to copy them out, I hit control C because it files I didn't want and the computer crashed. I will definitely not try to cancel the process again. Now I'm having trouble accessing the files again.

DiskRepair Utility
[image]
Repairing says it was successful but I still can't access. Also my hard drive used to show 121GB but now its only 60GB.

Here are the results of different commands

**diskutil apfs list**

`No APFS Containers found`

**diskutil list internal**

```
/dev/disk20 (internal, physical):
#: TYPE NAME SIZE    IDENTIFIER
0:           *60.7GB disk20
```

**diskutil list**
[image]
[image]

**gpt -r show /dev/disk20**

`gpt show: unable to open device '/dev/disk20': Input/output error`

**fsck_apfs -n /dev/disk20**

`fd_dev_read:380: blknum 0x0 size 128, error 5 dev_name = rdisk20`

[image]

I've tried using target disk mode with a firewire cable but did not see the mac when doing that. I just want to copy the files out onto an external hard drive I have. I really really could use help doing this. My mom didn't make any backups.